# What is actually happening behind the recursive function for large number?

Tags: c, recursion, computer-science

I have a recursive function below.

```
int f(int n){
  if(n<1) return 1;
  else return f(n-1) + f(n-1);
}
```

when I call the function with a small number like f(0), f(1) etc. it works fine.

but when I call **f(50)** or **f(80)** or **f(100)**, it just wait & no output displayed.

I need to know what is actually happening behind?

Comment: You are just experiencing exponential explosion in the processing time required. For this particular example you could optimize by observing that the two recursive calls give the same result.

Comment: Run your programme in a debugger.

Comment: "it just wait & no output displayed" -- how many years did you wait?

Answer (score 9):

## Naive Recursion

[Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) as defined by Wikipedia:

> Recursion is the process of repeating items in a self-similar way.

Your program is solving the mathematical [recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation):

```
f(n) = f(n - 1) + f(n - 1)
```

by calling itself, breaking the larger problem of `f(n)` into smaller and smaller chunks, and then breaking those chunks into smaller and smaller chunks, and so on.

What's happening when you call `f(0)`? Because the argument `n` in this case is zero, your base case is tripped and the recursive chain comes to a halt. This is is pretty simple case (as is any `n < 1`):

```
    f(0)
     |
     1
```

How about `f(1)`? A little more complex, but not much:

```
    f(1)
  /     \
f(0) +  f(0) = 1 + 1 = 2
```

Let's try something a bit larger, like `n = 5`:

```
             _____________f(5)___________
            /                            \
        ___f(4)____        +        ____f(4)____
       /           \               /            \
    f(3)    +     f(3)     +     f(3)     +    f(3)
   /   \         /   \          /    \        /    \
f(2) + f(2) + f(2) + f(2)  +  f(2) + f(2) + f(2) + f(2)
/ \    / \     / \    / \      / \    / \    / \    / \
...    ...     ...    ...      ...    ...    ...    ... = f(0) * 32 = 1 * 32 = 32
```

...so, it turns out that text trees are incredibly annoying to create by-hand. Hopefully, you're getting the idea by now. Maybe, you've even already spotted the pattern:

```
f(0) = 1
f(1) = 2
f(2) = 4
f(3) = 8
f(4) = 16
f(5) = 32
...
```

Generally:

```
f(n) = 2ⁿ
```

Mathematically-speaking, this is an exponential equation. In Big-O terminology, this is an algorithm that runs in *exponential time*. In more colloquial terms, this algorithm is really god-damn slow.

Think about what all is going on here:

1. The number of function invocations being made grows exponentially with the size of the input. Ouch!
2. Not only does the run-time of the algorithm suffer, so does the *space* complexity. Ironically enough, the issue that you're likely to experience with naive recursion is referred to as a **stack overflow**, where the function call stack *overflows* with an enormous amount of function calls and free stack space essentially runs out. Double ouch!
3. Not only do the time and space complexities of this function grow exponentially with the input, the algorithm is also very clearly doing *way* more work than it needs to be. What's happening every time `f(n)` is executed and the base case is *not* hit? `f(n - 1)` is calculated, **twice**. Triple ouch!

So, it's pretty clear that this algorithm sucks something awful. But what can be done about it?

## Common Subexpression Elimination

One optimization that goes a *long* way toward speeding up the run-time of your program is referred to as [common subexpression elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination). This is a very quick and simple optimization to implement, and it eliminates a vast majority of the function calls made by the naive version. All you need to do is realize that this:

```
return f(n - 1) + f(n - 1);
```

is equivalent to this:

```
return 2 * f(n - 1);
```

so that your code becomes:

```
int f(int n)
{
    if(n < 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    else
    {
        return 2 * f(n-1);
    }
}
```

Run this revision side-by-side with your original version and be blown away by the several-orders-of-magnitude difference between run-times! Because each invocation is only making a single recursive call, the exponential algorithm essentially becomes a linear-time (`O(n)`) straight-up recursive version of the equivalent iterative method.

Pretty cool, huh?

## Addendum: Dynamic Programming

*Though your specific example doesn't require dynamic programming as I originally believed it did, this is still a very useful topic to mention when talking about recursion, so I've reworked this section to be less contrived than it previously was. Also, this is an addendum in-part because I'll be using [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) syntax below. I apologize if this ruffles any feathers, I just don't relish in the idea of re-implementing [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)'s `std::map` at the moment (maybe in the future...).*

Maybe you've heard of [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). No, please don't cringe! It sounds scary, but it really isn't. Actually, it's pretty awesome!

**Very simply put, dynamic programming is an intelligent method of brute force.** The idea is that you *[memoize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)* previously-computed results into a lookup table so that that in the event that you ever need to recompute something (and with some algorithms, you're doing a **lot** of that) the answer is simply a constant-time (`O(1)`!) lookup away.

Let's take the example of the [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence). A standard, naive, run-of-the-mill implementation of the Fibonacci algorithm looks like this:

```
int fib(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
    {
        return n;
    }

    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}
```

The above is another exponential-time (`O(2ⁿ)`) algorithm. However, optimizing this algorithm isn't quite as simple as before, as `fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)` cannot be simplified in quite the same way. What we can do, however, is add a data structure designed to allow constant access to pre-computed results to our program, and leverage this to avoid a *ton* of redundant computation. The optimized version is thus:

```
long long fib_dp(int n)
{
    if (lookup.find(n) != lookup.end())
    {
        return lookup[n];
    }

    else if (n <= 1)
    {
        return n;
    }

    lookup[n] = fib_dp(n - 1) + fib_dp(n - 2);
    return lookup[n];
}
```

Add a lookup table (implemented as a [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) `std::map<int, long long>`), tweak the logic just a tad, and swap out plain-old `int` values for `long long` values, and you've got yourself a version of the Fibonacci algorithm that can handle much larger values of `n`, ***much*** faster. Seriously, try it out for yourself and compare. What the naive algorithm may take *hours* (or days, or more) to complete, the dynamic programming version can bang out in *seconds*.

So... I hope that all of this has answered your question (and maybe more). Let me know if you have any others! :)

**Follow-up:** Just to drive home exactly how inefficient your un-simplified expression can be - right around the time I first submitted this question, I ran both versions of this program (the simplified version and the naive recursive version) back-to-back on an input of `n = 50`. My desktop includes an Intel i7-4770K, and the relevant process is currently using about 13% of my CPU's processing power. The fast dynamic programming version finished within seconds with an output of `1125899906842624`. The naive recursive version is still working as I type, nearly twelve hours later. I imagine it'll be working a whole lot longer (if I allow it!).

*Thanks to Jim Balter for all your corrections, and making me realize that dynamic programming is useful but entirely unnecessary here! As usual, I've made things much more complicated than they need to be. OP isn't the only person learning something new here today! :)*

Comment: Great answer, detailed, easily understandable explanation of topics that were implied by the question! +1 :D

Comment: "stack overflow" -- The stack depth is the height of the tree, which is at most 100 for the OP's examples.

Comment: For this particular example, a simple way of "memoizing" is to note that the two subexpressions are the same, so `int memo = f(n-1); return memo + memo;` or just `return 2 * f(n-1);`

Comment: Fair enough. I think I got so excited about the prospect of referencing stack overflows on the Stack Overflow site that I didn't actually consider that. Good catch!

Comment: Also, `2 * f(n - 1)` is another very simple optimization I should have implemented. Updating now!

Comment: "it'll be working a whole lot longer" -- At 1 nanosecond per invocation of `f`, it would take 13 days.

Comment: With `2 * f(n-1)` all the results will be different so you'll never have a lookup hit. I think you should mention the subexpression folding and dynamic programming, as both are useful, but recognize that the latter isn't needed for this particular example.

Comment: I trust your math, but I'm not waiting around to find out! :)

Comment: Not my math, I just typed "2 ^ 50 nanoseconds" into google :-) [That number is the same as the answer you posted, of course]

Comment: OK, I've just realized what you meant by your above comment about dynamic programming being unnecessary. I assumed that this problem worked like a dynamic programming implementation of Fibonacci (though it doesn't), and went with that. I'll change my approach to the answer in light of this.

Comment: Since this question is tagged C and not C++, you shouldn't include any C++ syntax in your answer. You can provide a C++ solution as an addendum, but it isn't encouraged here at SO.

Comment: Yeah, all the values of f are powers of 2 so with `2 * f(n-1)` there are no repetitions, just a simple recursive implementation of an iteration.

Comment: Very good catches here. I think I'll keep the dynamic programming as a mention, but maybe I'll use Fibonacci as an example instead of OP's problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's happening what you've telled C to do, just that it will take a long time in big numbers such as `50` or `100`. Also, your code nevers output anything.

This will increase your program speed.

```
int f(int n)
{
if(n<1) return 1;
else return f(n-1) * 2;
}
```

Since `x + x` is the same that `x * 2`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Really all that the OP needed to know. My answer was probably a little over-the-top. Well done, @cdonts!

Answer (score 1):

The function actually return the value of 2^n.So in the case of smaller value the return value easily reside in the integer variable.But when the value of "n" become greater than 31 or so, integer return type unable to return the value so it doesn't show any output.

Comment: Precisely at n == 31, because the greates positive representable number is (2^31)-1. Doing ``int i = f(31)`` will take a while and then return -(2^31).

Answer (score 0):

Well lets look what happens when you do `f(x)` for `x = 2` and `x = 30`:

```
f(2) = f(1) + f(1) = f(0) + f(0) + f(0) + f(0) = 1+1+1+1 = 4;
```

We can see that for `x = 2` we get a relatively small chain of additions. We had to evaluate the function 7 times in order to get our result. Lets see what happens when we set `x` to 30:

```
f(30) = f(29) + f(29) = f(28) + f(28) + f(28) + f(28) = f(27) + ........ = 1+1+....+1 (2^30 times)
```

We see that we get a really long chain of additions and we have to evaluate the function many (sum (n=0 to 29) (2^n)) times. This many calls are what make the program so slow.

Comment: to get an idea `2^30` is `1,073,741,824`. `2^100` has 31 digits